# problem related to pigeon hole principle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

please help me to solve this using pigeon hole principle

Suppose that S is a set of n integers. Show that one can choose a nonempty
subset T of S such that the sum of all elements of T is divisible by n.

thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything? What did you find?

Comment: actually i learned this principle recently.so,i am somewhat confused.i don't understand any thing

Comment: So you have to think about divisibility by $n$ - there are $n$ possible remainders $0\le r \le n-1$. If you find a set with remainder $0$ you are done. So there are $n-1$ non-zero remainders. That gets you started. Then you need to find $n$ non-empty sets which are organised in such a way that if two of them have the same remainder you can find a set with zero remainder. That requires a little thought.

Comment: find n non-empty sets which are organised in such a way that if two of them have the same remainder you can find a set with zero remainder.can you explin this some more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is special case of the following:

> Prove that there exist consecutive terms with a sum divisible by n

Here, I explain with an example.

Let's assume $n=4$

and our set is $\{1,3,5,10\}$

Instead of working with numbers, we can work with the remainders. In this case we need to prove that there exist a (consecutive) sequence in remainders $(1,3,1,2)$ That have a sum divisible by $n$. 
 We make sequence of commulative sums of remainders for example for $(1,3,5,10)\equiv(1,3,1,2)$ 
$$1$$
$$1+3=4 \equiv 0$$
$$1+3+1=5 \equiv 1$$
$$1+3+1+2=7 \equiv 3$$
And we seek for a sum which is congruent to zero. If you found that, that is the answer. In this case that is $1+3$. If you did not find that zero, the remainders of sums can have $(n-1)$ values since there is no zero among them while the number of them is $n$. So two sums have the same value!!
In this case, $1$ and $1+3+1=5 \equiv 1$. Therefore, the subtract of these commulative sums still would be a consecutive sum with a remainder zero.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If the integers are $a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_n$, let, for $0\le k\le n$,
$$s_k=\sum_{j=1}^k a_j$$

(Of course, $s_0=0$).

How many different values can have $s_k\pmod n$? Must there be two of them $s_p\equiv s_q\pmod n$? What happens with $s_q-s_p$?

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer, can you explain why?